# What are the different types of documents needed for software development?

Tags: documentation, project-management

I am aware of Functional Requirement Document and Technical Specification Document. 
However, I would like to know, what are the different documents needed for an overall Project Development.

Let's say I have a small company, and I want to build a project for another company. What are the different documents I need to submit from the start to the finish?
And where do the FRD and TSD fit in?

Comment: Installation guide, Code of Conduct, API Documentation (Postman Collection), Knowledge-base documentation, Troubleshooting Documentation, Release Notes, Software Architecture Diagram, Recommended technical articles, Most used database queries

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Maybe these will be a good start:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_documentation

But I would say it all depends on the context. Different deliverables will be required for Agile projects as well as let's say RUP projects. This list should be agreed upon the target company/client..

Comment: ...old one... however I definitely support the statement "...it all depends on the context." Example influencing factors: project methodology, architecture maturity, finance and budgeting constraints, 'burned terms' in organizations that cannot be reused for any reason, skill of involved people...

Answer (score 12):

For developing a perfect software following documents are mandatory in series:

1. URS ( User Requirements Specification): The URS point wise describes all the requirements of the software.
2. UI: Depending on the URS certain pages of the software are designed. This also includes error messages, pop up messages etc.
3. SRS (System Requirements Specification): The SRS point wise defines system requirements depending on the URS.
4. STC (System Test Cases): After the software is developed system testing is done with and recorded in STC
5. UAT (User Acceptance Testing): After all system test cases are successful user acceptance testing in conducted to check if the software covers all points as mentioned in the URS and is prepared as expected
6. DTL (Defect Track Log): All bugs/defects recorded during UAT/STC are mentioned in DTL so that they can be fixed

After all bugs are fixed second cycle of STC and UAT is conducted to check if everything is fine now and fulfill user expectation. And finally the software is ready to use.

Comment: what about technical documentation?? i mean interface and code documentation for future review

Answer (score 4):

Go for the SRS in the first place. A legal written documentation is very necessary which will involve all the kinds of things that would be included in a software. It shows your professionalism.